# RNFFMpeg.executeAsync: Unable to create gif of a video with space(s) in it's source path

Tags: javascript, react-native, ffmpeg

Unable to make gif of a video which has space(s) in it's source directory. All the other video which don't have space(s), their gif is making fine. I had a video whose folder name had space and it was not making gif for it. I copied the same video to a folder without space in it's name, and it made gif for it successfully. Even if I replace the the space with source path with anything like %20 etc, then it says

> No such file or directory

**Code snippet**

```js
RNFFmpeg.executeAsync(
          `-i ${source} -ss ${start} -t ${gifDuration}  -vf "fps=5,scale=160:-1:flags=lanczos,split[s0][s1];[s0]palettegen[p];[s1][p]paletteuse" -loop 0 ${destination}`, (completedExecution) => {
            if (completedExecution.returnCode === 0) {
              resolve({ path: destination });
            } else {
              resolve({ error: "invalid Gif" });  // always this part executes for videos with space in their source path
            }
          }
        );
```

**Expected behavior**

Regardless a video has or has not a space in it's path, it should make gif correctly and

> completedExecution.returnCode

should be 0

Current behavior
Currently, for all the videos having space in their source path, completedExecution.returnCode is always 1

**Logs of the same video without space in folder name**

> [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:23:56.377] LOG file:///storage/emulated/0/AirDroid/VID-20210620-WA0024.mp4 [Wed Jul

> 07 2021 12:23:56.511] LOG [Parsed_palettegen_3 @ 0x7d62eb5ec0] 255(+1) colors generated out of 249823 colors; ratio=0.001021 [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:23:56.672] LOG video:48kB audio:0kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB

> global headers:0kB muxing overhead: [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:23:56.673] LOG

> 0.041083% [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:23:56.722] LOG {"path": "/data/user/0/com.tbox.pantry/cache/1625642625930.gif"}

**Logs of the same video with space in folder name**

> [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:20:45.577] LOG

> file:///storage/emulated/0/FMWhatsApp/Media/FMWhatsApp

> Video/VID-20210620-WA0024.mp4 [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:20:45.998] LOG

> file:///storage/emulated/0/FMWhatsApp/Media/FMWhatsApp: No such file

> or directory [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:20:45.998] LOG Conversion failed!

> [Wed Jul 07 2021 12:20:45.999] LOG {"error": "invalid Gif"}

**Environment**

"react": "16.13.1",
"react-native": "^0.63.3",
"react-native-ffmpeg": "0.5.1",
Android 11